# Create new DB in Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, backend, laravel-sail

When we create new project, DB is created automatically. What if we clone app from github? How can I create db? For example - i can logged to mysql in this command

```
./vendor/bin/sail mysql
```

Problem is that I couldn't create new DB becouse of no having privileges

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'testowa'
```

I found information that user sail doen't have privilleges to create DB and we need to logged like root but if i try logged in this command

```
./vendor/bin/sail mysql -u root -p
```

I'm not asking abot password I have this same error. Where problem is? How can I create new DB?

Comment: When you git clone, change the .env settings first before running `sail up`. If you already sail up before changing the .env, the new DB might not be created yet. so you may need to do `sail down -v` to delete old volumes then re run `sail up`